# reverse numpy reference cartesian product

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, cartesian-product

I'm using a function to get the cartesian product of 3 sets of arrays (cp1), which are derived from a column in a pandas dataframe. After obtaining this (cp2), I run a test to check if the sum is less than 1.05, and if it is I'd like find the combination from the original arrays that generated this from the position where it's true. Is there a way to do this with numpy / python / pandas? Any help would be appreciated. Ultimately I'd like to get the original indexes in each column in the dataframe that generated the true condition.

```
In [780]: cp1.shape

Out[780]: (8, 3)

In [781]: cp2.shape

Out[781]: (512, 3)

In [782]: cp2

Out[782]: array([[ 0.43478262,  0.33333334,  0.29411763],
                 [ 0.43478262,  0.33333334,  0.32258067],
                 [ 0.43478262,  0.33333334,  0.32786885],
                   ..., 
                 [ 0.43478262,  0.32258067,  0.32258067],
                 [ 0.43478262,  0.32258067,  0.29850748],
                 [ 0.43478262,  0.32258067,  0.32258067]])

In [783]: bools = cp2.sum(1) < 1.05

In [784]: np.where(bools)

Out[784]: (array([392, 398, 440, 446]),)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve for `ai` and `bi` in `ai * c + bi == idx` where `r < len(a)` and `c == len(b)` via `ai, bi = divmod(idx, len(b))`. This is the inverse of index calculation.

Another option that is more direct but uses far more space is to take the Cartesian product of `numpy.arange(len(a))` and `numpy.arange(len(b))` and then index it with your indexes to get the indexes in the original arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not really sure how to implement it.  I tried with 398, but I think I'm not doing something correctly. Could you provide an example using the numbers? The first solution is best as it'll be running many times, and I want to save space if possible.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I did some more work on this, and the 2nd solution works well, as it will only need to run a few times, if the condition is true. The first part needs to run many times, but this part is only a few times.